# how to get all data in correct way firebase-real-time-database JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase-realtime-database

I am using node.js and I am getting data from firebase real-time database. The problem is I am getting data something like this :

**for data getting code! JS**

```
import firebaseApp from '../config.js';
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";


const userRef = ref(database, "Users");
onValue(userRef, (snapshot) => {

if (snapshot.exists) {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data); // data printed to console
}

}, {
  onlyOnce: true
});
```

**Console Output**

```
{
  
 "random-user-id-1": {
    "name": "Jhon Doe",
    "profile": "profilelink",
    "email": "example@email.com"
 },
 
 "random-user-id-2": {
    "name": "Cr7",
    "profile": "profilelink",
    "email": "example@email.com"
 },

 // and more...

}
```

I want to display this data as an array of objects. Example of expected output

```
[

    {
    "name": "Jhon Doe",
    "profile": "profilelink",
    "email": "example@email.com"
    },
    
    {
    "name": "Cr7",
    "profile": "profilelink",
    "email": "example@email.com"
    }

    // and more........ ^_~

]
```

###### Any help will be always appreciated! and feel free to ask any doubts related to my question or problem!

thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you need only the values from your dict, you can transform your data this way:

```js
const lst = {
  
 "random-user-id-1": {
    "name": "Jhon Doe",
    "profile": "profilelink",
    "email": "example@email.com"
 },
 
 "random-user-id-2": {
    "name": "Cr7",
    "profile": "profilelink",
    "email": "example@email.com"
 },

}

const expectedFormatRes = Object.values(lst);


console.log(expectedFormatRes);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Gil's answer would be to use Firebase's built-in. `forEach` operation:

```
if (snapshot.exists) {
  let values = [];
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    value.push(child.val());
  })
  console.log(values);
}
```

While longer, this has the advantage that it maintains the order in which the database returned the data, which becomes relevant when you specify an `orderBy...` clause on your query..